# How can I set minutes to make a hibernation in Ubuntu through the Ubuntu Terminal?

Tags: shutdown, hibernate

I know how to hibernate just at the time using:

> sudo pm-hibernate

What I need is hibernate in the next 60 minutes. 
For example, when you wanna shut down in 60 minutes you type:

> sudo shutdown -h 60

How can I make the same action but for hibernation?

Answer (score 2):

You may use `sleep` command. [It accepts](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sleep) postfix `m` to numbers, which stands for minutes. I.e. you can execute

```
sleep 60m && someCommand
```

Now, here's a little problem that `sudo` after a time limit requires to enter the password again, and if you'd execute `sudo sleep 60m && sudo somecommand`, the *someCommand* wouldn't do in time. To workaround it, execute everything in a separate shell with elevated rights using the `-c` option of `sh`. I.e. the command would be:

```
sudo sh -c "sleep 60m && pm-hibernate"
```